# Gulp tasks customization

Tags: gulp

I am new to gulp, I need some help customizing tasks, I think my question is pretty simple but I did not mange to do it myself

I am using this [file](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mgechev/angular2-seed/master/gulpfile.ts) to compile, I have a folder called assets in the dist folder, I do not want this folder to be copied each time I change sources. is there a way to ignore this folder when it compiles. Gulp-ignore is already there but I did not mange to override tasks

I checked the contents of the file, the definitions and sources are included in this [file](https://github.com/mgechev/angular2-seed/blob/faa0343e05b145c2837076965fc0a888ba64d5e2/tools/tasks/build.assets.dev.ts) other definitions are in this [repo](https://github.com/mgechev/angular2-seed/tree/faa0343e05b145c2837076965fc0a888ba64d5e2/tools/tasks)

Comment: I don't see your `gulp.src` commands, but have you tried the exclusion pattern is supports? for example `gulp.src(['!assets/**/*.js', '**/*.js']).pipe(..)`

Comment: this is what I am struggling with, I read things different that what I have on this file

Comment: There has to be (at least to my knowledge) some kind of 'for these files' instruction for gulp. This is done using the `gulp.src` command. Can you update your question to contain the relevant parts (e.g. one complete task including the path structure, please don't paste the entire file)

Comment: I updated the questions based on your advise, the sources are included there

Comment: Ok, for once I dug around in your repo (I could find the repo fine, I meant the code itself ;-) ). You have something like `return gulp.src([join(APP_SRC, '**'),'!' + join(APP_SRC, '**', '*.ts')])` in `build.assets.dev.ts`. In there ('!' rules should be on top!), you can add the exclusion for `assets`, something like `'!' + join(APP_SRC, 'assets', '**', '*.ts')`